# Using hier.part Package on R, getting an "invalid type (character)" message

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, hierarchy

I am trying to run a hierarchical statistical analysis on a set of data involving insect sizes in R-studio using the `hier.part` package. Each data point includes the following data: month of collection, year of collection, the average yearly temperature, average monthly temperature, and the length of the insect's wings (elytra).

When I try to use this code:

```r
indv <- subset(dataset, select=-elytra)+

hier.part(y = dataset$elytra, xcan = indv, family = "gaussian", gof = "RMSPE", barplot = TRUE)
```

I get this error:

```r
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

I have already converted every column to numerical data, so I am not sure where the (character) data is coming from to interfere with the analysis. The data set I am working with is large and somewhat complicated, so I am trying to run a simple analysis first, but I can't seem to get this package to work for me.

Apologies if the formatting here is not good, this is my first question. If you need any more information about my data or the problem, please let me know. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is a  `+` following `subset` --- this seems like a typo. Do you need to convert character vectors to factors? You are much more likely to get help if you can provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This requires work on your part, but on the other hand when you're asking for help you're asking others to do work to help you. Are you able to use the package with one of the built-in datasets? Comparing those dataframes to yours might provide a clue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.